# google workspace calendar stops syncing on android after a few weeks

Tags: google-workspace, android-calendar

My workplace uses *google workspace*

I have setup my android phone and online accounts in linux to sync calendar data from this account.

Every few weeks both these devices stop syncing data. The old recurring event data is retained but no new invites show up on my calendar.

There is no notification on either my phone or laptop that the calendar syncing has stopped and I realize it only when someone informs me that I was a no show at some critical meeting.

The only way I can get the account working again is to remove it and add it again.

My personal gmail accounts do not have this problem on both the devices.

I assume this is due to some token expiry event. Any hints on where the problem is and how to fix it?